# jQuery date picker to select only month and year?

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery date picker to select month and year only?. I tried it using date format, it working but show dates too. I am trying a way to select month and year only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, that's not possible. It's a date picker, you can't omit date from the output. 
Your best bet would be to:
1) grab the month and year using date format
2) use two separate drop down lists, one for month and one for year